# Elasticsearch - provided multi-field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in my index with a duration field, represented in a period/duration format, e.g. P1DT3H4S.

Ideally I'd have Elasticsearch parse that into milliseconds in a multi-field. Apprently Elasticsearch cannot do that.

The next best thing is to convert the period into milliseconds myself and store it in a multi-field. Is this possible?

What I would like to end up with:

`duration` with a value like `PT4M20S`.

`duration.millis` with a corresponding value of `260000`

Comment: it's possible to have ES compute it for you, but the result would not be stored in a multi-field, just in two separate fields. Would that be ok for you?

Comment: I could do that in code and store in a separate field. But how do you make Elasticsearch compute it?

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself from that logic and have ES do it for you using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) with a [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html).

First you need to create an ingest pipeline that will take the duration string and parse it into milliseconds:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/duration2ms
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
            ctx.durationInMillis = Duration.parse(ctx.duration).getSeconds() * 1000;
          """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when you index your documents you can reference that pipeline, like this:

```
PUT index/_doc/1234?pipeline=duration2ms
{
  "duration": "P1DT3H4S"
}
```

And the document that will be indexed will look like this:

```
{
  "duration" : "P1DT3H4S",
  "durationInMillis" : 97204000
}
```

Comment: Could I in this case have an alias named 'duration.millis' that refers to durationInMillis?

Comment: What difference does it make? You can name that field however you like

Comment: Since duration is already a keyword, it cannot be an object. So I cannot simply store a document that has both a duration (keyword) field and a duration.millis (long) field

Comment: Yes, and that's why you need two different fields, multi-fields won't work here. You could have an object field `{"duration": {"keyword": "P1DT3H4S", "millis": 97204000}}`

Comment: Technically this works just fine. The problem I have is that the duration field is public and has to have the value as the ISO duration. Also, the users can query the data using lucene syntax. I would _really_ have liked to have the users be able to refer to the millisecond value as duration.millis.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to have a field that is not of object or nested type or multi-field that contains other sub-fields. If you think about it, both fields have completely different types, so it makes sense that if you want to search on them you need two different fields.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible exactly like I'd want. There are issues open for elasticsearch to support ISO durations natively so I'm just keeping my eyes on those.

Comment: Well, if you're talking about [this one](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/39857), they never provide any roadmap nor deadlines for feature requests, they might not even support durations the way you expect, so good luck with that. I can't count how many times I've been in your situation. The solution has always been this one: use a temporary quick hack and prey that the feature request will make it through one day... or the other solution I've done a few times: develop it yourself since it's open source.